# Convert HTML output to a different structure with PHP DOM

Tags: php, html, dom

I have a simple HTML file that I need to read some values from and change the structure of for HTML email output. I'm fairly new to scripting/PHP/navigating the DOM, so forgive me if this is a simple question.

Below is the initial output:

```
<table id="Table_01" width="600" height="547" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">
                <img src="header.jpg" width="600" height="295" border="0" alt="Alt Text 1"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <a href="http://url.com/1">
                <img src="leftcell_link1.jpg" width="300" height="163" border="0" alt="Alt Text Left"></a></td>
        <td>
            <a href="http://url.com/2">
                <img src="rightcell_link2.jpg" width="300" height="163" border="0" alt="Alt Text Right"></a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">
            <a href="http://url.com/3">
                <img src="body_link3.jpg" width="600" height="89" border="0" alt="Body Alt"></a></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Here is the desired output:

```
<table id="Table_01" width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2" width="100%">
                <img src="header.jpg" border="0" alt="Alt Text 1"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td width="50%">
            <a href="http://url.com/1" name="link1">
                <img src="leftcell_link1.jpg" border="0" alt="Alt Text Left" name="link1"></a></td>
        <td width="50%">
            <a href="http://url.com/2" name="link2">
                <img src="rightcell_link2.jpg" border="0" alt="Alt Text Right" name="link2"></a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2" width="100%">
            <a href="http://url.com/3" name="link3">
                <img src="body_link3.jpg" border="0" alt="Body Alt" name="link3"></a></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Some things of note

- The structure of the input file will not always be the same.
- The "td" widths, which are based off a percentage of the width attribute of the child (or grandchild) "img" node compared to the total email width (in this case, 600px).
- Attaching the custom "name" attribute to the "a" and "img" tags based off a substring of the image "src" attribute.

Would I be best to deconstruct the entire thing into an array of the required element attributes then reconstruct it in the correct format? Or would it be easier to loop through the DOM and look for the attributes I need then apply them to the parents and delete unnecessary attributes where needed?

And is there any way to handle this all recursively so that I don't need multiple levels of checks based on whether it's at the "td" "a" or "img" level?

Answer (score 0):

You can change what you want with DOMDocument class.

```
<?php

$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML('<table id="Table_01" width="600" height="547" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"> <tr> <td colspan="2"> <img src="header.jpg" width="600" height="295" border="0" alt="Alt Text 1"></td> </tr> <tr> <td> <a href="http://url.com/1"> <img src="leftcell_link1.jpg" width="300" height="163" border="0" alt="Alt Text Left"></a></td> <td> <a href="http://url.com/2"> <img src="rightcell_link2.jpg" width="300" height="163" border="0" alt="Alt Text Right"></a></td> </tr> <tr> <td colspan="2"> <a href="http://url.com/3"> <img src="body_link3.jpg" width="600" height="89" border="0" alt="Body Alt"></a></td> </tr> </table>');

$tds = $doc->getElementsByTagName('td');

$tds[0]->setAttribute('width', '100%');
$tds[1]->setAttribute('width', '50%');
$tds[2]->setAttribute('width', '100%');

var_dump($doc->saveHTML());

?>
```

result:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd">
    ...
       <td colspan="2" width="100%"> 
    ...
       <td width="50%"> 
    ...    
       <td width="100%"> 
    ...
</html>
```

Please read documentation of this functions: 
http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php

Comment: Thanks tsv. I'm aware that you can change what you want, but the structure of these HTML files won't always be the same and I should have outlined that in the question. Apologies. 

Sometimes there will be a two-column TD, sometimes there will be images that aren't links, sometimes there will be images that are links, sometimes these images will be inside two-column TDs.

Basically wanting a way to recursively read elements then re-write them in the format that we require.